# Access parseJSON by string name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm jsoning a c# const class, getting name-value-pairs. I need to access them by string-name on client side, e.g.

```
return $.parseJSON(constantClass).'property';
```

This is obviously not working - is there any way to get my value from my json-input using a string name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to access them as array keys (very familiar to associative arrays):

```
return $.parseJSON(constantClass)['property'];
```

See **[more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)** how you can operate with objects at MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
JSON.parse(constantClass)['proptery']
```